# VirtualBox: Windows7 is host, Ubuntu is guest - how to configure hosts to VirtualBox when networking is 'bridge'?

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu as guest on VirtualBox on my Windows 7 host machine as web server for my PHP/Ruby projects.

I set networking in VirtualBox setting to 'bridge' so now I can access my VirtualBox server by something like 192.168.2.26 - it is generated by DHCP every time so it is not static.

Is it possible to make it static or get VirtualBox IP in Windows so I could set 'virtualbox' in hosts in Windows and go in browser to 'Virtualbox' address as I can go 'localhost'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Ubuntu guest edit `/etc/network/interfaces` you'll see something like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

change it to be similar to this

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.26
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.2.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
gateway 192.168.2.254
```

using parameters that make sense in your network. Restart networking with

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 2):

On ubuntu guest set the static ip-address by editing the file /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.26
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway windows-machine-ip-adress
```

And also, place the ip-address of windows machine in resolv.conf.

resolv.conf file typically contains directives with the IP addresses of nameservers available to a host.

```
#vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

nameserver     windows-machine-ip-address

And restart the network service.